# SQL Update Latest rows for a distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to set the SGNumber = 2 for the last modified for each unique MaterialeNo.

Start table:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

If it is of any help, i made a select query that only selects the latest of each with each MaterialNo, which are the rows i want to update

```
select distinct MaterialeNo, max(SGNumber) as tag 
from Mydatabase
group by MaterialeNo
```

Comment: Insert the result of the query to a temporary table(#tmpSample) and then update your table by joining the temporary table to the main table.

Comment: What if there's a duplicate material no on same date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a join of the table to the query that gets the max LastModified:

```
update m
set m.SGNumber = 2
from Mydatabase m inner join ( 
  select MaterialeNo, max(LastModified) as MaxLastModified 
  from Mydatabase
  group by MaterialeNo
) t on t.MaterialeNo = m.MaterialeNo and t.MaxLastModified = m.LastModified
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c59a2421a44d5dfac651a93da45873b5).
Results:

```
> id | MaterialeNo | LastModified        | SGNumber
> -: | :---------- | :------------------ | -------:
>  1 | test1       | 05/07/2019 00:00:00 |        1
>  2 | test1       | 06/07/2019 00:00:00 |        2
>  3 | test2       | 04/07/2019 00:00:00 |        1
>  4 | test2       | 05/07/2019 00:00:00 |        2
```

Comment: what if there's id = 5, materialNo = test2, LastModified = 05/07/2019 00:00:00? so 2 records will be updated?

Comment: The requirement is: *I want to set the SGNumber = 2 for the latest LastModified of each MaterialeNo*. If there was a case of 2 rows of the same MaterialeNo having the same LastModified I guess the OP would mention.

Answer (score 1):

Use This. using your row ID to make sure those items with same LastModified and MaterialNo wont get updated.

```
Update MyDatabase  
Set SGNumber  = 2
FROM 
(select t1.id from 
    (select id, row_number() over (partition by MaterialNo order by LastModified desc) rownum from MyDatabase) t1
Where t1.rownum = 1) t2
WHERE MyDatabase .id  = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MS SQL Server you can do it with row_number it will count (same item and set order number for id) how seems  in your case i show you have latest dates at the end se you can achive it simply

### so you can check this sample i did for you

```sql
Declare @Mydatabase  table (Id int identity(1,1),MaterialNo varchar(20),LastModified datetime,SGNumber int)

insert into @Mydatabase values ('TEST 1','2019.07.05',1)
insert into @Mydatabase values ('TEST 1','2019.07.06',1)
insert into @Mydatabase values ('TEST 2','2019.07.04',1)
insert into @Mydatabase values ('TEST 2','2019.07.05',1)

select Id,MaterialNo,LastModified,SGNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MaterialNo ORDER BY LastModified ASC) Numbering
from @Mydatabase
```

### results

```
Id  MaterialNo  LastModified             SGNumber   Numbering
--  ----------  -----------------------  --------   ---------
1   TEST 1      2019-07-05 00:00:00.000  1          1
2   TEST 1      2019-07-06 00:00:00.000  1          2
3   TEST 2      2019-07-04 00:00:00.000  1          1
4   TEST 2      2019-07-05 00:00:00.000  1          2
```

Comment: Actually I needed to update the table, not make a select. This does not update the table itself. 
But I might have been unclear under my stress, I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE and `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MaterialNo order by LastModified desc) as rownum 
      from mydatabase t
     )
update toupdate
    set sgnumber = 2
    where seqnum = 1;
```